# rack-offline in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, offline-caching

I am trying to setup rack-offline in Sinatra, but I am having trouble setting it up. In rails it is prettty easy, but have no found any examples in Sinatra...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in your `config.ru`, map `/application.manifest` to `Rack::Offline`. (If you're not familiar with using `config.ru` with your Sinatra application, check out [this part of Sinatra docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Using%20a%20Classic%20Style%20Application%20with%20a%20config.ru).) Here's an example, which caches all the files under directory `public`:

```
require 'your-app'
require 'rack/offline'

map "/application.manifest" do
  offline = Rack::Offline.new :cache => true, :root => "public" do
    # Cache all files under the directory public
    Dir[File.join(settings.public, "**/*")].each do |file|
      cache file.sub(File.join(settings.public, ""), "")
    end

    # All other files should be downloaded
    network '/'
  end

  run offline
end

map "/" do
  run Sinatra::Application
end
```

Remember to set `manifest="/application.manifest"` in your `html` tag and you should be good to go. You should take a look at [rack-offline's README](https://github.com/wycats/rack-offline#readme) for more documentation and explanation of how it works.